# TypeError: Cannot set property 'Id' of "Null"

Tags: javascript, html

When I run the code it does work in browser but the error keeps appearing.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="dashboardJob">
  <script>
     var i = 0;
     do {
        document.getElementById("dashboardJob").id = "dashboardJob" + i;  
        i++;
     }
     while (i < 40)
  </script>
</div>
```

Is anyone able to point out what i'm missing here?

Cheers

Comment: Think about what happens when the code tries to run the loop the *second* time. Is there still an element with id `dashboardJob`?

Comment: Yeah I can post more code but this code comes after a loop that displays a div for every row in a database.

Comment: Just put <script> tag outside your main DIV. the reason it is not working is, that once browser sees an opening <script> tag, it starts to execute the code, but at that time, the DIV has yet not been closed, this why you get error

Comment: I am assuming there is just the one div with the id of "dashboardJob". After the first time through, the div now has id "dashboardJob0". The second time through `document.getElementById("dashboardJob")` will return null so can not assign id of null.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem to me, especially reading your last comment. Script tags are not scoped by element.

Comment: Loop runs once and replaces the id of "dashboardJob" with "dashboardJob0".  Loop throws an error the second time because there is no longer an element with id of "dashboardJob".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `<script>` tag below the DIV

```
<div id="dashboardJob">

</div>
<script>
     var i = 0;
     do {
        document.getElementById("dashboardJob").id = "dashboardJob" + i;  
        i++;
     }
     while (i < 40)
 </script>
```

The reason it is not working is, that once browser sees an opening script tag, it starts to execute the code, but at that time, the DIV has yet not been closed, this why you get error .

**EDIT**

Your code will not work. I am not sure, what are you trying to accomplish, but if the loop runs for the first time, you change it's ID attribute, then the second iteration will fail, since there will not be DIV with ID `id="dashboardJob"`, but with `id="dashboardJob-1"`

Answer (score 1):

During the first iteration of the do-while loop, `document.getElementById("dashboardJob").id` will return null as it hasn't encountered the `div`'s closing tag.

Also, you're trying to dynamically change the `id` 40 times for the same element. Not sure if that is what you're trying to achieve with the code. However, it won't again during the 2nd iteration since during the 2nd iteration there is no element with id `dashboardJob`.